# Dataclasses in Python: What to do with complex types as arguments?

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses

I have begun to embrace the dataclass decorator for classes that are primarily containers for data. All of the tutorials and examples I have seen are for relatively simple variables, with types like int, str, float, list, tuple, or dict. I have two issues with dataclasses:

1. I have never seen a list of what types are implemented in dataclasses.
2. I have never seen an example of how to handle types that are not implemented in a dataclass.

The second issue is the focus of this post. So is there a methodology or a best practice if you have a dataclass that has attributes that are more complex (e.g. a pandas dataframe, a function, an instance of a user-generated class)? I can think of two likely options: a) handle the complex types manually in _*post_init*_, or b) "build" a type that describes the argument (I don't know how this would be done, it just seems possible)

Here's roughly how I might implement option a:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class movie:
    release_year: int
    title: str

    def __post_init__(self, cast_table):
        cast_table = cast_table # A dataframe containing cast information
```

Comment: What type is `cast_table`? If it has type `Foo`, you can just add `cast_table: Foo` to your series of attributes. The part after the `:` just has to be a type.

Comment: Per the comment in the assignment, cast_table is a dataframe. So you're saying I can just put ```cast_table: pd.core.frame.DataFrame``` in the attributes? Huh, I was sure I had tried that before and it didn't work.

Comment: Even with the self answer, the question does not make sense to me. Can you clarify just what exactly you are asking? What do you mean by "what types are implemented in dataclasses"? ``dataclass`` does not care about the types of its field at all, with the exception of the markers documented for the ``dataclasses`` module. The ``dataclass`` decorator is not implemented for any specific attribute types, it works with all of them.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, yeah, that's the point I didn't get. I had been working under the assumption that the decorator would have to have "handlers" for each type. Just never occurred to me that it could handle them generically.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner), here's: how to do what I was asking:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pandas as pd

@dataclass
class movie:
    release_year: int
    title: str
    cast_table: pd.core.frame.DataFrame

tabl = pd.DataFrame(data={'Actor': ['Graham Chapman', 'John Cleese', 'Eric Idle'], 'Role': ['King Arthur', 'Sir Lancelot', 'Sir Robin']})
mphg = movie(title='Monty Python and the Holy Grail', release_year=1975, cast_table=tabl)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, but did you find a way to produce a better OUTPUT than this?

```
movie(release_year=1975, title='Monty Python and the Holy Grail', 
cast_table=            Actor          Role
0  Graham Chapman   King Arthur
1     John Cleese  Sir Lancelot
2       Eric Idle     Sir Robin)
```

This is fine, because it's like a Pivot Table output that is aggregated for the year and title.  But it's just messy on the screen and a little challenging to run with this data as a DataFrame.  Do you know of a way to have the output come out to be like.......

```
    Actor            Role         release_year        title 
0  Graham Chapman   King Arthur    1975        'Monty Python and the Holy Grail'
1  John Cleese      Sir Lancelot   1975        'Monty Python and the Holy Grail'      
2  Eric Idle        Sir Robin      1975        'Monty Python and the Holy Grail'
```

instead?....................

Also, you omitted your comma "," at the cast_table = tabl

```
mphg = movie(title='Monty Python and the Holy Grail', release_year=1975 cast_table=tabl)
```

correction

```
mphg = movie(title='Monty Python and the Holy Grail', release_year=1975, cast_table=tabl)
```

Comment: It looks like it is out of scope of this question and more of a new question. You can redefine the `__repr__` method to get the output you like though it is recommended that the output of the `__repr__` method looked like it can be called to create an instance. Like `movie(title='Monty Python and the Holy Grail', release_year=1975)`. It is better to implement custom method for the output you chose like `print_table()` or something.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

With the `DataClassJsonMixin` you can use `config` add an `encoder` and `decoder` that serializes the data type. Thismay not make sense for something as complicated as `pandas.core.DataFrame`, but I see no reason it shouldn't work.

If you do go down this route, because of the implication that from `DataClassJsonMixin` that the structure is to be serialized to and from `json` it is good practice to make the `encoder` and `decoder` inverses of each other, so that you can read back what you write out.

Here are some examples for `Enum`, `datetime`, and `Polygon`

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from dataclasses_json import config, DataClassJsonMixin
from marshmellow import fields

from datetime import datetime
from enum import Enum

from urlpath import URL
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from shapely import wkt


class BeamMode(Enum):
    IW = 'IW'
    EW = 'EW'
    S1 = 'S1'


FORMAT: str = '%Y-%m-%d'


@dataclass
class FootprintMeta(DataClassJsonMixin):
    beam_mode_type: BeamMode
    md5sum: str
    url: URL
    frame_number: int
    geometry: Polygon = field(
        metadata=config(encoder=wkt.dumps, decoder=wkt.loads)
    )
    timestamp: datetime = field(
        metadata=config(
            encoder=lambda d: datetime.strftime(d, FORMAT),
            decoder=lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, FORMAT),
            mm_field=fields.DateTime(format=FORMAT),
        )
    )
```